# Is it possible to apply before/after selectors to an attribute selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Good day.

I am trying to apply a global CSS rule across my website so that all links to files will open in a new window.  The current situation is that the website has a bajillion links and files all over the place, so I am trying to resolve this matter with a CSS rule.

I wish to know whether I can somehow use the attribute selector:

```
a[href*="/files/"]
```

Then use :before or :after to insert **target="_blank"** into the link code.

Is it possible?  If so, can anyone show me the CSS to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking to use :before/:after to insert attributes? Then it's not possible, because these are pseudo-*elements*, not pseudo-attributes or pseudo-DOM-nodes, etc. Furthermore, the concept of pseudo-attributes wouldn't make sense in CSS, since attributes are concerned with structure and meaning, and not presentation. If you want to change an element's attributes, you use the DOM APIs to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You can do that with jQuery instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href*="/files/"]').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khb49zg3/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the specks for :before and :after limit it to text and css driven counters. I recommend using a javascript solution. If your page is static, then something on the onload will do. For more dynamic pages, jquery or similar will help. What technologies are you using?

Comment: It's in Drupal 7 and I have very limited access, even though I am asked to solve the problems.  I may have the ability to use JQuery, not sure yet.

Comment: Sigh, that adds an extra level of complexity. No only do you need to trigger change, but you must do this every time Drupal loads a new page. I am not knowledgable on Drupal, but it appears you need to use behaviours (https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal).

Comment: ... and https://www.drupal.org/node/756722. You will get better help if you re-ask the question with a what you want to do, rather than the how - and tag it Drupal. Say if you have access to the Drupal instance or are using an installation provided externally as this will change the approach needed.